# Nuget handling of libraries in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

We have a set of functionality that was previously in a regular dll file, but that is now in a Nuget package. Naturally, we want to pull it using Nuget instead of having to download and update the dll:s manually. All projects are handled in VS 2013, so we have access to it through the package manager.

Now, we need to go over all the projects in the source tree to update the reference to be a nuget reference instead of the old dll reference.
You can do this on a solution level using the package manager, but since there are several dozens of solutions and well over a hundred projects I'd rather not do it manually.

Is there a way to automate this? That is, to iterate through the source tree, find every .sln file and update the references in its underlying project files?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it by writing a small C# program. Install NuGet.Core and NuGet.VisualStudio package to the program to use functions in nuget.core.dll and nuget.visualstudio.dll, plus some DTE functions.